# Wscript.Quit gives error 424 in VBA for word

Tags: vba, ms-word, wsh

I am writing some code in VBA for Word to redirect users to a link if they would like to or to close the window if not using a yes/no box. The problem is that if the user does not want to continue to the link, the code gives an **error 424: Object required**.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
intMessage = MsgBox("Would you like to read about alternatives to these words?", vbYesNo, "Access Denied")
If intMessage = vbYes Then
objShell.Run ("LINK")
Else
Wscript.Quit
End If
```

**The Error 424 highlights 'Wscript.Quit'** when I debug the error.
How to I resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You say this is Word VBA - sor are you trying to quit Word? If so why are you trying to use `Wscript` to quit?

Comment: @dbmitch more likely a copy-pasted snippet from some VBScript sample.

Comment: @dbmitch, sorry! I am inexperienced with coding and am just learning. I found this code from a different source and I am trying to make it work for me. I didn't realize this was the wrong thing to use!

Comment: "Access denied" is not an appropriate title to match your MsgBox question either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WScript` is a VBScript object. You're writing VBA code. Remove the instruction altogether, `WScript` is undefined and means nothing.

You're getting that error because, in your code, `WScript` is a `Variant/Empty`, only because `Option Explicit` is missing from the top of your module, which allows VBA code to compile & run without validating that every variable is properly declared (this means typos happily compile & run as well) - in other words it's an undeclared variable, and since you're making a member call on it, per VBA syntax this could only be an object... except it isn't, hence "Object required".

- Remote the instruction.
- Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module
- Declare all variables. Look into how to use the `Dim` statement.

Comment: Thank you! Removing 'Wscript.Quit' resolved the issue!

Comment: @ShaneMulholland and adding `Option Explicit` in every module will prevent many more ;-)